# JSS/CSS class names are clashing in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

There are two different classes in Next.js I have defined in JSS with different names and in different components. But after compiling, both are getting same name (Eg. `jss136`). I'm using MUI. Is there a bug in MUI `makeStyles()` method or something with Next.js?

Comment: Yes this is a common issue, SSR is tricky to setup with Material UI because of the way the class generator work. You also maybe have another issue with SSR (like using router query params too early, anything that breaks rehydratation), because usually Mui works ok in Next. At this point, focus on updating to Mui v5 and get rid of JSS, you won't get much help on this. You'll be better of with v5, which is based on Emotion.